# Global setting to have time stamp pre-pended to all lines outputted to terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, timestamps

I'm working on a server where there are many different shell scripts used to trigger processes. These shell scripts use echo commands primarily to produce terminal output that is captured by an agent into log files. I want to find a way to pre-pend a time stamp to all these output lines from the terminal.

I have read about the ts command from moreutils. It is infeasible to have every call to these scripts re-written to pipe through ts (based on business processes) so I was thinking a possible solution would be to find a way to have every command run on the instance to pipe through ts. Is there a way to do this, or is there a better way to prepend the timstamps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45123073 see if this solves your issue.

Comment: Read `man logger`. Using `echo` for logging sucks, as years of experience tells me.

Answer (score 0):

You can define echo alias for that

```
$ alias echo='echo $(date -u)'
$ echo "log line"
Mon Dec 27 23:30:44 UTC 2021 log line
```